# ElasticRTC cluster turn server iceServers

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento, turn

I've installed kurento elasticRTC, with `EnableTurn` set to TRUE.

I successfully connected to the Kurento media server, at the given URI in Cloud Formation Output.

Then i opened the inspector, with the credentials specified in the stack creation, and in server info i found this json data:

```
{
  "clusterPublicIps": ["54.244.**.**"],
  "clusterMetadatas": [{
    "iceServers": [{
      "urls": ["turn:54.244.**.**", "turn:54.244.**.**?transport=tcp"],
      "username": "9d46b7b8f4b***b3b334452d50cba837",
      "credential": "8be235d48f0c08bd9d8f1ad25*******"
    }],
    "publicIp": "54.244.**.**",
    "localIp": "10.0.41.201",
    "version": "6.5.0.20*****172436.trusty"
  }],
  "connectedMember": "******-b273-4d53-8a79-d78fa7aed417"
}
```

(I obscured some fields for privacy and security reasons)

BUT, when i used the iceServers string in my Browser Application, it doesn't work!

I'm sure my app works because i already made it work with a custom kurento/coturn installation, but i can not with this automatic configuration.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think those TURN/STUN URLs are used internally for Kurento to get the EC2's pubic IP, and that you'll need to use a service like xirsys or twillio or setup your own TURN service for the client side webRTC connection.  I think this is the case because normally the TURN credentials expire after x number of seconds.

Comment: It should be documented somewhere, right? I got the credentials from the Kurento Inspector, they ddn't expire. I really don't understand -.-

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i used elasticRTC tools CLI commands and it works.

I suggest who will read this post to use it and not trust the automatic script on AWS marketplace!